# Scripts in my Google sheet not working After Downloading

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google sheet with some Google Scripts..here its working fine,But After Downloading and opening these scripts are not working. Is there anything to do for working these scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Scripts can only run on Google servers. You cannot download them and run locally.